# Using the same libraries of different versions

Tags: glassfish, dependencies, classpath

I have 2 libs: **owls.jar** and **envy.jar**. They depends on lib **jena.jar** but two differnet, incompitables versions. envy using old version - **jena.jar**, owls new - **jena2.jar**
I want to use them togever at web application running on ***glassfish-3.0.1***. I`m using ***IDEA 11*** for deploying my web app.

I have directory tree like this:

- webapp/web-inf/lib/envy.jar
- webapp/web-inf/lib/owls.jar
- webapp/lib/envy/jena.jar
- webapp/lib/owls/jena2.jar

I add into **manifest.mf** of envy and owls libs class-path like this: ***../../lib/envy/jena.jar***

I use ***-verbose:class*** option and I always get loaded class from **jena.jar**.If I`m using or not using **envy.jar** at all, I always get loaded class from **jena.jar**. Only if I delete **envy.jar** then classes loads from **jena2.jar**

Is there are any way to use both of this libs?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to use 2 different version of the same class is to laod them through 2 different classloaders. That is you have to load **owls.jar__and __jena.jar** with one class loader and **envy.jar** and **jena2.jar** with another. This solution has its own pitfalls, you should probably right custom code that will be able to use another classloader when it's necessary, maybe you will end up with writing your own class loader.

As far as I know there is no built in solution for such situation. May be, it is easier to use older version of one the jar's above that can support the same version of **jena.jar** This is much easier solution.

Comment: May be you can give some example? I only know how to load classes and then access them using reflection, but I don't know how to load classes for some 3dparty library. I know how to load **owls** classes, but how I can load classes of **jena2** for **owls** lib?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use library wich uses a new version of **jena**. And also I need another lib wich uses old version of **jena** and there will be no further updates of it. So as I understand there is no way to do it? Or I could do with my own class loader? If yes, then may be you know something what I can read about it(how to load classes for 3dparty libs)?